# How to config nginx so it serves php for all routes but only for one specific route it serves static html file?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a website created with php, but some routes needs to bypass the php and only get served as static html file.

Here is what I need: http://localhost/reports will open some static index.html file, but all other routes like: http://localhost and http://localhost/xxxx will be served by php.

Here is the nginx config I tried, it only serves the php part, when I try http://localhost/reports it gives 404 not found, I also tried many different configs including the `alias` directive, none of the worked correctly.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.php ;
    # there is an index.php file inside public directory
    root /var/www/newproject/public;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /reports/ {
        # there is an index.html file inside static dire
        root /var/www/newproject/static;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        # For comfortable debugging
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```